# Pass value of dynamic button to modal form

Tags: javascript, php

I am dynamically creating a table with output from a SOAP API.  This all works.  The last table column on the right creates a button that has a value dynamically created by output from the API.

On button press, it opens a Modal that requires the button value to be passed to it into the modal form that upon submit is passed back into the API to set a reservation.

Everything works EXCEPT passing the exact button value from the page to the modal.  When I simply add a call to the php variable it either does not add the button value OR it adds the value of the last pulled value from the API.

PHP Snippet of Dynamically Created Table

```
<?php
// Make API Call
$result = $client->getAllUnitTypes($sessionId, $argv[3]);
// Process Results
if($result['success'] == "true") {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result['xml']);
    foreach($xml->root as $item) :

        if($item->Total_Number_Vacant != 0 && $item->billingplansetname == "Small"){ 
?>
<tr>
        <td><? echo $unitName = $item->Type_Description; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $item->web_Description; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $item->Web_Promotion_Description;  ?></td>
    <td><? echo "$ ".$item->Minimum_Price.".00" ;  ?></td>
    <td><? echo $item->Climate;  ?></td>
    <td><? echo "<button class='button' id='Unit_Name' onclick=\"document.getElementById('reservation').style.display='block'\" style=\"width:auto;\" name='UnitType' value='".$unitName."'>Reserve</button>";  ?></td>
</tr>
<?php   } 
    endforeach;
    echo "</table>";
    } ?>
```

Modal HTML (Just the header section)

```
<div id="reservation" class="modal">  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="submitReservation.php" method="POST"> 
    <div class="container">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('reservation').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">X</span>
<span style="text-align: center;"><h2>Apply for this unit</h2></span><span style="text-align: center;"><h3>Please fill out this form, and a manager will be in touch shortly to confirm your move-in date and payment details.<br>Applying for: <?php echo $_POST['unit_Name']; ?></h3></span><input id="facility" name="facility" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $argv[3]; ?>">
```

Javascript for Modal

```
var modal = document.getElementById('reservation'); 
window.onclick = function(event) { 
    if (event.target == modal) { 
        modal.style.display = "none";   
    } 
}
```

In the MODAL I need to get the exact value of the button from the table as dependent upon the HTML value (which is verified as correct in the page source).

For example:
Unit Size ***|*** Price/Month ***|*** (Button)
Size 1    ***|*** $10.00 ***|*** (Button value="Size 1")
Size 2 ***|*** $20.00 ***|*** (Button value="Size 2")
Size 3 ***|*** $30.00 ***|*** (Button value="Size 3")

EXPECTED: When button for "Size 1" is pressed, the modal will open and display:

> You are applying for: Size 1

ACTUAL RESULT: When button for "Size 1" is pressed the modal will open and display: 
Either...

> You are applying for:

OR

> You are applying for: Size 3

I'm not sure where the issue is.

EDIT: Form Handler Script

```
<?php //Submit Reservation
require("connect.php");

$reservationOptions = new stdClass();
    $reservationOptions->firstName = $_POST['fname'];
    $reservationOptions->lastName = $_POST['lname'];
    $reservationOptions->email = $_POST['email'];
    $reservationOptions->mobilePhone = $_POST['cell'];
    $reservationOptions->homePhone = $_POST['home'];
    $reservationOptions->street1 = $_POST['address'];
    $reservationOptions->city = $_POST['city'];
    $reservationOptions->state = $_POST['state'];
    $reservationOptions->zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $reservationOptions->moveinDate = $_POST['moveIn'];
    $reservationOptions->unitId = $_POST['unit-name'];



    // Get arguments
    if(!isset($argv[1]) || !isset($argv[2])) {
        print "Usage: ".$argv[0]." <<username>> <<password>>\n";
        return;
    }

    $client = new SoapClient("<<API URL>>");

    // Login    
    $sessionId = $client->authenticate($argv[1], $argv[2]);

    // Check Login
    if(!$sessionId) {
        print "Login Failed.\n";
        return;
    }
// Make API Call
    $result = $client->saveReservationWithOptions($sessionId, $_POST['facility'], $reservationOptions);

    print_r($reservationOptions);
?>
```

Comment: You need to have your Javascript populate the value into the modal, not your PHP.  Add a `span` or something where you want the text to be and give it a unique ID.  Then, on button click, populate that element with the value of the clicked button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Applying for: <span id='unit-name'></span></h3>
```

And create a function to open the modal:

```
function openModal(element)
{
     document.getElementById('reservation').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById('unit-name').innerText = element.value;
}
```

Change the button `onclick` to call that function:

```
onclick=\"openModal(this)\"
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works as I need it for that step.  Now how do I pass value through the form into the form handler script?

Comment: I updated the original post to include the form handler script.  Your change worked as I requested, so thank you very much.  Just needing to pass it into the form script to pass into API.

Comment: @AaronB you need to actually open a new question as this question was already answered.